# Azure Application Insights - API to query data outside of Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am using Application Insights to monitor multiple webjobs and it's work great ! I've built some dashboards through the Azure Portal and configured a Continuous export so that users can have the data into PowerBI.

And now I've got a demand to be able to view metrics from an existing application that monitor others jobs. So just wondering if there is an API to query data from Application Insights ?

I did not find any thing for the moment...

Thanks.

Comment: Not quite the same, but we continuously export data into an Azure Blob Database, and then access it from there. There's an added cost but, depending on how much data you're generating, it will probably be quite cheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Thomas,
We are indeed working on an API and the first part of it that will be ready is the availability to query metrics. Such an API is the [#1 request](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/4999529-make-data-accessible-via-apis-for-custom-processin) at our [UserVoice forum](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/category/77108-application-insights).

Thank you

Dale

Comment: Thanks Dale, I will follow this request.

Comment: Hi Dale, any update on this? I'm also interested in getting the Application Insights results outside of the Azure portal.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the exact same thing.  I found this API that is apparently in Preview.

https://dev.applicationinsights.io/reference/get-query